# What is arepa flour?

Tags: cornmeal

I found a recipe for arepas that I want to try and it calls for "Arepa flour (precooked cornmeal)". What is Arepa flour? Side question: Would I be able to substitute masa harina?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From  [Cook's Info](http://www.cooksinfo.com/arepa-flour) :

> Arepa Flour is a refined, pre-cooked corn flour ("harina de maiz refinada, precocida".) It is not the same as the masa harina that is used in Mexico; for Arepa Flour, large-kerneled corn is used that has large, starchy endosperms, making for a starchier flour than that which is used for tortillas.
>
> There are white and yellow varieties of the flour, because the corn used may be yellow or white.

Also:

> For commercial makes the corn is hulled dry. The hull is first removed from the seed, as well as the germ. Then the kernels are cooked, ground, dried and packaged.
>
> Arepa Flour is sometimes referred to as a "pregelatinized" flour because the grain has been cooked first.

I'm thinking that masa harina would not be a suitable substitute for making Arepas. Another thing I've found is that corn flour is usually finer than corn meal, even if the corn meal is ground 'fine'.